# How to configure 2 files in 2 dependent instances in cloudformation script?

Tags: iis, aws-cloudformation, hosts

I am doing a lift and shift with software from an on-premises architecture. There are two servers (main and auxiliary) that have to talk to one another over the network. I currently have tested and confirmed that I can manually add their hostnames and private IP address to the hosts file (`"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"`) and the software works fine.

For those that don't know, this file is used by Windows to map a network hostname like `EC2AM-1A2B3C` to a IP address. So if I added the hostname and IP address of the main server into the hosts file of the auxiliary server, then the auxiliary server could route to the main server. (i.e. `PS> ping EC2AM-1A2B3C` would then work).

How could I pass the required information to both servers? They both have to know the other server's private IP address and hostname. If this is not possible at server spin-up time, how might the servers connect and pass this information? I would really like to automate this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have some suggestions that you can refer to.

1. If you want two EC2 instances to be able to communicate with each
   other, you can use the method of adding rules to the security group.

   (1) Create security groups for your instance 1 and instance 2 respectively.

   (2) Add an inbound rule to the security group of instance 1, chose "ICMP-ipv4". Enter the security group ID of instance 2.

   (3) Create the inbound rule for instance 2 in the same steps.

   For more information on security group rules you can refer to the [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-security-groups.html).
2. You have tried adding the hostname and IP address of the primary
   server to the host file of the secondary server. To tell each other
   the IP Address of the other machine. Amazon CloudFormation cannot
   handle the circular dependency between the two instances.

   You can refer to the answer of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/487015/how-to-make-ip-address-known-on-both-instances-in-an-amazon-cloudformation-templ). To realize that both instances know each other's IP address.

   Hope these suggestions are useful to you.